# Do I need to call 'django-admin.py startproject PROJECT' command to start a new Django project?

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I'm starting a new Django project using google cloud and Bitnami Django distribution.

I copied a working project from my local machine to a cloud instance to a projects folder, restarted Apache, but unfortunately, I cannot see my site from outside.

According to the documentation, to start a new project I need to run a command `django-admin.py startproject PROJECT`

Do I need to run this command for a copied project?

Comment: Look at your apache error logs. Most probably located at `/var/log/apache2/error_log`.

Comment: No, `django-admin startproject` is not required for a copied project. There are other reasons why you can't see your app running. Check your logs.

Comment: @nik_m could you share a command to check logs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google cloud but with a simple search I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer_v2).